# Postgres: Can I identify which tables are write-heavy in a schema using the statistics?

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to identify which tables in our schema see the heaviest insert/update load.

Is there a way to easily count the number of inserts/updates that have been issued on a specific table within a specific time range?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pg_stat_user_tables` for that.

Use `pg_stat_reset()` to reset the statistics, then wait a while.

The columns starting with `n_` will tell you which tables receive the most writes.